# How to recover the data from a drive whose partition table is changed?

Tags: data-recovery, bios, partition-table

I recently wanted change my partition table so, I backed up all my data and changed it but after that was done I found that some of my project files were not pushed to GitHub and then I tried to recover it with **testdisk** but it didn't worked I did a `deep search` too it still didn't found it please anyone tell me how to recover that data it was super super important!

I will really appreciate help! ♥

#### Some info:

I am currently using a MBR partition table
I have a legacy BIOS Firmware
I have a HDD
I am on manjaro linux

Comment: It is not possible to help you without knowing *exactly* what you did. Edit your question and include the commands you ran to backup, aswell as what you did to change the partition table.

Comment: I backed up my data by creating a tar.gz file of them and then uploading it to cloud storage

Comment: I used ```New Partition Table``` in **Gparted**

Comment: Is that information enough please now tell me a way to recover that data  and if anymore information is needed please feel free to ask

Comment: I am not sure what I am missing, but can't you recover that file from the tar ball? Also there are tools to find deleted partitions: https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=recover+deleted+partition+linux.

Comment: bro it's not working I said that I have tried testdisk several times

Comment: What filesystem did you have on your partition before the change? Did you create new files on the new partiions? Did you try `photorec` to recover the files?

Comment: I had ext4 file system and yes I created new files and I also tried photorec

Comment: ???????????????

Answer (score 3):

Since you have created new files on the new partitions, your old files may be completely lost, overwritten by the new files. Let's assume this did not happen and that your files are still there somewhere.

Since tools don't help, then you can try searching for your files manually. For this, you need to know a string that was present in your file, preferably a string that is *only* in the files you're looking for.

Assuming you're looking for the string `my forgotten source code` on your disk `/dev/sda`:

1. Find all strings on your physical disk: this may take a loooong time if your disk has large capacity:

```
strings -24 -t d /dev/sda | grep -i "my forgotten source code"
```

- `-24`: minimum length of strings to look for, adjust accordingly
- `-t d`: print offset in decimal

This will return the offset where the strings were found. If you have no result, then your files may have been overwritten and there may be no way to get them back. On the other hand, you may have a lot of results, if your string appeared in multiple files or multiple git revisions of your file. You'd better store the results in a file if it takes too long or if there are too many matches, so that you can analyze the results again later. Just don't store the file on the same disk to avoid erasing your lost files!

2. Browse the disk bytes near the offset found. Assuming you found the string at offset 1024:

```
xxd -s 1024 /dev/sda | less
```

- `-s 1024` start reading the disk bytes at offset 1024, adjust accordingly if you need to read before the beginning of your string.

Sources: https://www.lmgsecurity.com/sleuth-kit/

Comment: can I search for the name of the archive?

Comment: I found the files but how to get them back? they were here - 56436605392

Comment: 47846654400 unnat.tar.gz
69019369482 unnat.tar
69607645632 unnat.tar.gz
69612322868 unnat.tar.gz
69612331456 unnat.tar.gz
69661417920 unnat.tar.gz
This was the result

Comment: This method is only valid for the *content* of the file, and only for plain text files. I don't have a clean solution for getting the whole files back: you will be able to see the plain text in `xxd` output and copy the text from there.